# nameof(NotNullValidator) doesnt work for .Net5 and FluentValidation 10

Tags: c#, .net-5, fluentvalidation

Good afternoon,

I updated my project to .Net5 and updated the FluentValidation.AspNetCore to version 10.3.0.
In unit tests I usually make the following

```
ErrorCode = nameof(NotNullValidator)
```

but now with this version change I had error because the NotEmptyValidator is a T class i.e.

```
public class NotNullValidator<T,TProperty> : PropertyValidator<T, TProperty>
{
public override string Name => "NotNullValidator";

public override bool IsValid(ValidationContext<T> context, TProperty value)
{
    return value != null;
}

protected override string 
GetDefaultMessageTemplate(string errorCode)
=> "A value for {PropertyName} is required";
}
```

I don't know the way to get the name of validator. The same happen with all validators.

Can you help me with it please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Providing an empty generic type parameter into `typeof` will successfully compile and return you the type. You can then access the `FullName` property to get the string representation.

```
ErrorCode = typeof(NotNullValidator<,>).FullName
```

Note though that the returned string will contain the generic specification at the end to indicate that it's a generic class, like this:

```
NotNullValidator`2
```

Comment: Yes, I got this result, but I'm trying to get the class name directly.